# Error when submitting my app to AppStore: "Missing required icon file.... exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0."

Tags: ios, assets

I get this error when trying to submit my App to AppStore (deployment version is iOS 10).

**Submission was fine before iOS 11 & Xcode9.**

I am using an Asset catalog containing all required AppIcon.

[image]

This question is not a duplicate.

After several hours I found an interesting thread on CocoaPods GitHub.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7003

It seems that this is a CocoaPods problem when a POD is using xcassets.
I was able to submit my app to Apple by removing this xcassets from pod (temporary) and add it to my projets manually.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Basically, this is a "he said she said": you are claiming that your icons are correct but the App Store is claiming that they are not. I tend to believe the App Store.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I am using Assets with all icons set and added to target. Post you mention is about xCode 5...

Comment: I don't know whether it's a duplicate or not. But you have given _no_ information about your hard information about your project, and therefore it is right to close the question, as there is nothing to answer. You have said only that iTunes Connect thinks there's something wrong with it. Well, I put it to you that that's probably because there's something wrong with it.

Comment: I found what causes the problem.